# PHP - SUM number according to item name

Tags: php, mysql

Am new in PHP, I need help in my scripts since I don't get preferred answer.
I have a "bills" table which store information's of sales items. as folows

```
id | gid | drinks | no_drinks | servicetime | date
1     2    Orange   4            1           2018-08-16
2     2    Orange   2            1           2018-08-16
3     2    Orange   3            1           2018-08-16
```

Below file (BillsController.php) query gid, servicetime and date, and the query is equal to true.

BillsController.php

```
 $bi = Barz::whereRaw('gid=? and servicetime=? and date=?', array($gid, $t,date('Y-m-d')))->get();

        return View::make('bills.show', compact('bi'));
```

Below is "show.php" file which display the information's from Database. I will just shows you few things in it.

```
 <?php
$foods = array();
foreach($bi as $row){
$foods[]  = $row->drinks;
$idadi[]  = $row->no_drinks;

$unique = array_keys(array_count_values($foods));
$l      = count($unique); 
}
  $newarr = array();
  foreach ($unique as $key => $value) {
  array_push($newarr, $value);
 }


 ?>


    <table class="table table-bordered" id="gt">
<tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
    <th>Drink</th>
    <th>Qty...sx</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>@cost</th>
    <th>Total@</th>
    <th>
        <select class="form-control active" id="tserv">
    <option value="{{$row->servicetime}}">{{Bill::tm($row->servicetime)}}</option>
        <select>  
    </th>
</tr>
<?php $total = 0; ?>
@for($i=0; $i < $l; $i++)

    <tr>
        <td>{{$newarr[$i]}}</td>
        <td>{{$idadi[$i]}}</td> // Only problem is here
        <td>{{Bill::appears($newarr[$i], $foods)}}</td>
        <td>{{Bar::where('name', $newarr[$i])->first()->cost}} /=</td>
        <td>{{($idadi[$i])*(Bar::where('name', $unique[$i])->first()->cost)}}/= </td>
    </tr>
<?php $total = $total + (($idadi[$i])*(Bar::where('name', $newarr[$i])->first()->cost)); ?>
  @endfor
<tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
    <td ></td>
    <td ></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td id="ttl">
        {{$total}} /=
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I run above query, I get 4 from ("{{$idadi[$i]}}"), which means it take only first row, and the rest is not selected. I want it to do like this (4+2+3) = 9.

Answer (score 0):

To add columns together;

`SELECT col1, col2, col3, (col1+col2+col3) AS Total FROM`

To add rows together, use the `SUM()`

Aggregate below;

`SELECT userid, SUM(col1) AS col1_total, SUM(col2) AS col2_total FROM table GROUP BY userid`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

select SUM(no_drinks) no_drinks from table_name GROUP BY drinks